# How can I conveniently retime an image sequence strip in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, timeline

I'm putting together a "movie" of stills.  I would like for these stills to have animated scale and position, and to change to the next image only every nth frame-- let's say, every 16 frames.  In order to match the beat of a song.  (I am adjusting both framerate and "base" frame in order to get 16 frames equal to the length of a single, 132bpm, beat.)

My basic problem is that an image sequence displays one image for every frame, and I can't see a way to change that to every 16th frame.  I have attempted a few different workarounds.  These all create problems for me.

1. Speed strip, where I make a speed effect strip and specify the start and end frame and linear interpolation between the two.  This has the problem where I have to adjust all of the timings of scale/position keyframes on the base strip whenever I change the timing on the speed strip, because the speed strip reads the *image* on the frame specified, but the keyframes from the actual frame.  (Interestingly, position keyframes on the source strip update immediately, but scale keyframes don't update until a frame scrub.)  I can't place these keyframes on the speed strip itself, because it doesn't know anything outside of video borders from the source strip, so if I scale the speed strip down from an oversized source strip, I get alpha borders.  Speed strips are also undesirable for causing significant performance problems.
2. Adjusting a combination of properties/output/format/ FPS and base, and /frame range/time stretching.  The problem with these is that it doesn't seem to read my off-true-frame keys.  The only keyframes that get read seem to be keyframes at integers, so I can't use it to change position or scale of images that are, before rescaling, only a single frame long.
3. Adjusting the strip length.  I've tried a variety of methods, from specifying start and end time in the sidebar, to specifying a length in the import image sequence file dialog sidebar.  In every case, it starts with the first image, advance one image per frame, and if the length of the strip is longer than the number of images, it just holds the last image until the end of the strip.

Is there any other technique that I'm missing here?

Comment: is using an image sequence a "must have"? or can it be basically a plane with that image "somehow"? I think animation nodes could make this pretty easy, if i understood you right

Comment: You know, at first I was thinking VSE was necessary for convenient strip arrangement and intuitive scale/position, but I might be able to do it just as conveniently with NLA arrangement and object coords.  Personally, I wouldn't be interested in AN (but would probably use GN for material assignments, for organizational purposes) but an AN answer might be useful to somebody else in the future if you feel like offering it.

Comment: @Chris Oh yeah, I see, I can't even retime in shader nodes.  Yeah, an AN solution might be best here, and I'd be interested in one.  (It's really amazing how much faster an Eevee render does video though, it's probably easily worth it to work in a 3D viewport instead of VSE.)